# Bitwise Logic knowing what was enabled from the server

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I am after some quick code to help with my logic on bitwise code (my first time doing it)

Basically I have 3 properties each with an ID of 1,2,4

```
int A = 1 
int B = 2 
int C = 4
```

Lets say A and C are checked, this will equal 5 and this value will be saved into the database. Good.

Now I need to work out on the way back what was checked with that value.

So in the example, the value is 5, so how will I know with bitwise logic what properties were checked?

So I am not asking for you to do my work, knowing what I do,

```
int i = A & C;
// if i == 5, then we know it was A and C checked
```

But do you need to do that for each possibility?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You're describing pretty much _exactly_ what `enum flags` are supposed to do: http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/07/22/c-fundamentals-combining-enum-values-with-bit-flags.aspx

Comment: Or else just use bit shifting and bitwise AND to test the bits.

Comment: I know and I agree, however, I choose not to use a enum because rendering a enum on a view looks messy, but you;re right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check for these conditions:

```
i & A != 0  // true if A is set in i
i & B != 0  // true if B is set in i
```

Having said that, bitfields are inappropriate in lots of situations. Especially when you store the resulting value into a database it is usually better to just define some more columns storing each flag.

Comment: Thats how I would do it and agree, however, as the question says, I am new to bitwise logic (in the programming sense) and as I am only dealing with 3 values (1,2,4) thought it would be a good time to start! and thanks will mark when SO lets me